# Chrome closes TCP connection after response

Tags: c, google-chrome, http, firefox, tcp

I have this code that handles some very basic http requests. I want it to support persistent connections. If I request some pages through firefox the session/connection is reused as indended. Chrome, however, closes the connection after each request/response independent of whether the *Connection: keep-alive* header is included or not.

Is this intended or is my read/write loop wrong?

```
#include<sys/socket.h>

// some setup code

listen(sockfd, 5);

// accept new connections
while (true) {
  int session_sock_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);
  if (newsockfd < 0) {
    // error
  } else {
    // create session
  }

// session main loop, each session runs in its own thread
while(true) {
  int n = read(session_sock_fd, buffer, buffer_size);
  if (n < 0) {
    // connection time out or some error
    break;
  } else if (n == 0) {
    break; // client has closed the conneciton
  }

  // parse the request

  // send response
  char* resp_data = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n"
                    "Content-Length: xxx\r\nDate: some  date\r\n\r\n"
                    "response_body\r\n";
  n = write(session_sock_fd, resp_data, size);
  if (n < 0) {
    // error, unable to write to socket
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your content-length include the final `\r\n` in your `resp_data` or only `response_body` ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich No it didn't, I changed it. It seems to work as intended now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my problem was that I didn't include the final "\r\n" when I calculated content-length. It seems to be working now!